# Convert SharpDevelop 3.1 solution to VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, solution, sharpdevelop

Is there a way to open a solution created in SharpDevelop 3.1 in Visual Studio 2005?

Here is the header of the solution file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
# SharpDevelop 3.1.1.5327
```

Is it as simple as changing the version numbers in the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying the solution file header, I was able to open and compile the solution in VS2005.  Looks like file format is the same.

Here is the modified header:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 9.00
# Visual Studio 2005
# SharpDevelop 3.1.1.5327
```